# Can't get UIButton image when getting UIButton from [self.view viewWithTag:n];

Tags: objective-c, uiview, casting, uiimage, uibutton

I can't get this piece of code that simply get the image of the `UIButton` to work. The error message keeps saying that tempButt is a `UIView` and it will not respond to the call `imageForState:`.
Can someone tell me why and how to do it correctly?
Ultimately I want to compare this image I get with another image to see if they are the same.

```
UIButton* tempButt = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:tagNum];
UIImage* tempImage = [tempButt imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have set image to background image or as image if you hae set image as background image try this

```
UIImage * img = [btn backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can set image as contant and another image as background this code will get background image

Answer (score 0):

Are u sure u have added the button as a subview to self.view(in xib or code) and  have set its tag property to the value held by tagNum??  Just check em once..

I presume u might have gone wrong in one of the above mentioned cases..

If it happens to be a button then I'm sure  either one of these calls should get u the buttons image..

A button has two properties image and backgorundImage..

For getting image use

```
 tempButt.currentImage  (or) [tempButt  imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For getting backgroundImage use

```
 tempButt.currentBackgroundImage
```

Please note that imageForState method only works if u have set image to buttons image..

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I really thank you for your effort in helping me. I checked everything you've said but that didn't help. I don't know why...